# What is the usefulness of the package "erewhon"?

Tags: fonts, packages, text-manipulation, number

I'm using a preset overleaf project for MSc thesis and I found that the package `erewhon` produces numbers that do not align with the text. In my thesis I have many numbers that are not necessarily phisical quantites as dates, names of asteroids and so on.

Here is a MWE of my project, note that some packages were already commented when I got this project:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbats
%%\usepackage{marvosym} % for \Keyboard etc deactivated by because it enter in conflict with "mathabx" package

%\usepackage{lmodern} % originally commented
%\usepackage{newtxtext} %originally commented
\usepackage[osf]{erewhon}% extension of Utopia, osf=old-style-figures
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% sans typewriter
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{cabin}% sans serif

%\usepackage[utopia,vvarbb]{newtxmath} %deactivated because it enter in conflict with "mathabx" package

\usepackage{textcomp}% AFTER newtxtext to avoid clashes


\usepackage[TM]{ar}

% \usepackage{textgreek} % (Greek letters outside Math mode)
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

123456789

\num{123456789}

a

ExampleNUM342

Example date: 24-Jan-2022

example years: 2021/2022

serial number: N45/0054963

asteroid 2007 UN12

\textit{a}\\
$\mathfrak{a}$\\
$\mathfrak{b}$\\
$\Omega$
$\omega$

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

My question: is it acceptable to have this format or is it better to use another font (as `lmodern` for example)? How I have to typset numbers that are not phisical quantities (that I manage with `siunitx` package), i.e. asteroid names, dates and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `osf=old-style-figures` says it all. Remove the `osf` option to have lining ("normal") numbers, which are more fit for tables etc. Your question doesn't have anything to do with the font itself.

If you want tabular figures, as per page 4 of the manual of the `erewhon` package:

"`\textlf` and `\texttlf` render their arguments in proportional and tabular lining figures respectively, no matter what the default figure style. E.g., `\textlf{345}` produces 345"

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm a novice and unfortunatley I do not have sufficient time to read the documentation. However, can you tell me when/why one should use `osf` ?

Comment: You can use it if you like. Think of `osf` as lowercase numbers, as there are lowercase letters (p, q, ç) that go below the line. It's mostly used in running text. For tables and formulas (math) some people don't recommend them. And by the way, the `erewhon` documentation doesn't explain this (although it wouldn't cost you more than 2 minutes to peruse).

Comment: Thanks again. Let's assume that I want to use it but with some exceptions. How to avoid the osf when I have to typset outside mathmode?  For example, I want to write `asteroid 2017 UN12` without osf. How to proceed?

Comment: osf is font-level, so you could define two font families, same font name, but one switches on osf, and the other does not, and use the non-osf one for asteroid names, e.g.: `{\mynonosffont 2017 UN12}`.

Comment: @Giuseppe, see answer update for this particular package.